# empty array in C and returning a pointer

Tags: c, arrays

I am very new to programming in C and i am unsure about creating a function that creates an array with space allocated for the array and have it return a pointer to the array. Here is what i have so far:
**Edit**

```
struct Array {
    int* sort;
    int arraySize;
    int totalSize;
};


array* createarray(int elements)
{
    int arr[elements];
    int *p;
    int *p_array;
    p = &arr;
    p_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*elements);
    return p;    
}
```

Is this the correct way of making an empty array list? And explain if its not please?

Comment: Post the definition of `list`.

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends.

Comment: Since you do not return `p_array`, you leak memory. Also, you do not need to cast the result of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Split out your work into separate functions. Do not cast `malloc`. For instance:

```
int* create_array(int elements)
{
    int* p = NULL;
    p = malloc(sizeof(int) * elements);
    if (!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate space for array\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;    
}

struct List* create_list(int max_elements) 
{
    struct List* l = NULL;
    l = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    if (!l) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate space for list\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    l->sortedList = create_array(max_elements);
    l->size = 0;
    l->maxSize = max_elements; 
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Seems like to get an upvote you need to contextualize this code? Maybe add some more detailed explanation.

Comment: *I am very new to programming in C* are the first words in the question. Just an extra comment here and there would be helpful i think. Anyway, this is right ... +1

Comment: @AlexReynolds You appear to prefer initialising pointers to null and then allocating on a separate line. I'm curious, is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: If you don't explicitly initialize their value, their value is undefined. So if you `free` it later on, if you set it to `NULL` then it should be okay to do so. Otherwise, who knows what happens. Better to be explicit, in my opinion. Others may disagree.

Comment: @AlexReynolds How is that relevant in this instance, where you are allocating on the following line, and then exiting if allocation fails? (As opposed to allocating immediately, I mean.) If you had a `goto cleanup;` or similar in the function I would see the benefit... but not so much here.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Wasn't me. I see the other answer is +1/-1 too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to return a pointer to a brand-new instance of a `struct List`.  This is a common idiom in well-structured C programming, and is analogous to the combination of an object constructor and operator `new` in C++.

I might write something like this:

```
struct List *newList(int maxSize)
{
    struct List *lp = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    if(lp == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return NULL;
        }
    lp->sortedList = malloc(maxSize * sizeof(int));
    if(lp->sortedList == NULL)
        {
        free(lp);
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return NULL;
        }
    lp->size = 0;
    lp->maxSize = maxSize;
    return lp;
}
```

There are several things to note here:

- Here I declared the passed-in `maxSize` parameter as `int`, although a better type would probably be `size_t`.  (By the same token, `size_t` might be a better type for the `size` and `maxSize` fields in the structure.)
- Notice that I called `malloc` twice, for the structure and for its internal "array".
- notice that if the second `malloc` fails and causes the whole `newList` call to fail, it frees the previously-allocated but now-unneeded `lp`.
- this function prints a message to `stderr` and returns `NULL` on failure, requiring the caller to check for that.  Other strategies would be to print a message and call `exit`, or to print nothing and return `NULL`.